# php go-pear.phar on Debian Testing does nothing

Tags: php, debian, pecl, pear

I have a fairly fresh Debian Testing install, and I am trying to install PEAR / PECL but when I run the command nothing happens. I don't want to install the PEAR package in the Debian repositories because in my experience it is too old. I have installed php5-dev.

Here is what I tried:

```
$ wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
$ php go-pear.phar
```

I also tried `sudo php go-pear.phar`.

```
$ php -version
PHP 5.3.6-13 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jul  4 2011 12:42:46) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
with Suhosin v0.9.32.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2010, by SektionEins GmbH
```

Any thoughts how I can see what is going wrong here?

-- Edit

if I do: `php -i | grep phar` I get:

```
Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip  
Phar-based phar archives => enabled
Tar-based phar archives => enabled
ZIP-based phar archives => enabled
phar.cache_list => no value => no value
phar.readonly => On => On
phar.require_hash => On => On
```

There is no phar.ini in `/etc/php5/conf.d/`.

-- Edit 2

I have installed PEAR from the Debian repositories now and run `pear upgrade`. Still interested to figure out why the go-pear.phar installation is not working.

$ whereis php

```
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/share/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

$ whereis pear

```
pear: /usr/bin/pear /etc/pear
```

Comment: Do you mean it didn't show the prompt after typing `php go-pear.phar`?

Comment: No, I mean it shows the prompt immediately afterward, without showing anything else. Just in case it was a silent install I tried running both pear and pecl. The system did not recognise the commands, so I assume they weren't installed.

Comment: What does prompt say?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, I thought you meant the commandline prompt. I enter after the command and am immediately returned to the commandline prompt. There is no output or prompts from the `sudo php go-pear.phar`. This is what I meant when I said nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php#106590) is what worked for me. Tested on a Debian Squeeze amd64 installation:

```bash
$ php -d suhosin.executor.include.whitelist="phar" go-pear.phar
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ php -d phar.require_hash=0 go-pear.phar
```

---

```
pear: /usr/bin/pear /etc/pear
```

It means that the PEAR is already installed. Type `pear -version` to check its version. Uninstall it first and try again.

Comment: No, that didn't make any difference.

Comment: What is the output of: `whereis php`, `whereis pear`?

Comment: See my edit to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting situation is if you are listening for remote XDebug connections and pecl is driven by PHP, so it may catch and break the process.